# Qt QML fails to render text correctly on some systems

Tags: qt, qml, label, qt5, rendering

I have so far seen this issue on a Win 7 PC, not sure if it will happen on all Win 7 PCs?

As you can see, the text 'Personal Info' defined at the top inside a QML Text{..} box is incorrectly rendered:

[image: incorrectly rendered text]

I realized that the text below the header was working fine, this is defined as a Label{...}, so I replaced the Text object with a Label object recompiled and ran on the target machine and it now works -

[image: working using Label{...}]

The code is compiled with Qt 5.10.1 minGW 32bit.
The qml file is fairly long, the area in question is as follows:

```
Rectangle{
    id:titleNameContainer
    color: "transparent"
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: parent.width
    height: 40
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    CenturyGothicFont{id: nameStrFont}
    Label{
        id: nameStr
        text: "Personal Info"
        width:parent.width
        //color: "black"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font{
            family: nameStrFont.name
            pixelSize: 30
        }
    }
}
```

The 'label' was a 'text' object.

The text itself is an imported font of type .ttf, this font clearly works when used as a label.  I have not made any changes to the anti aliasing settings as asked in the comments (I would have to look this up if I wanted to / need to).

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Err... what does your qml code look like?

Comment: Please improve: Qt version ? Font name ? Windows 7 32 or 64 bit ? Development environment (mingw ? MSVC ?) Antialiasing setting ?